# Typography and Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm facing a difficulty to transpose my idea of slide into LaTeX code.

Here is the idea [image]

Basically it's formed with

- 3 description items
- sub item description text
- curly brace with the same font of the text
- bullet points items

So far I achieved the description items and a TiKz solution for the bullet points.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{frame title}
\begin{description}
    \item[description item] \hspace{.5cm} \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(A.center)}]
        \node[text width=7cm,align=center] (A) {\begin{itemize} \item some bullet points \item some other bullet point \end{itemize}};
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt},color=blue] (A.south west) -- (A.north west); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Would really appreciate how to implement the sub item description text and the curly brace with the text font scaled to the height of the bullet point items.

Looking for a TikZ based solution.

Comment: Please post what you have achieved so far.

Comment: editing right now...

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post a compilable minimal working example, starting with `documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: done. nothing special there.

Answer (score 10):

Real easy with `stackengine`, and some `scalerel` thrown in for the brace.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\parskip .5cm
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{frame title}
\stackunder{\parbox{5cm}{Description Item 1}}{%
  \hspace{1cm}\Longunderstack{%
    --- sub item 1\\
    --- sub item 2
  }%
}
\scalerel[.3cm]{\{}{%
  \Centerstack{%
    $\bullet$ bullet point 1\\
    $\bullet$ bullet point 2\\
    $\bullet$ bullet point 3
  }%
}

\stackunder{\parbox{5cm}{Description Item 2}}{%
  \hspace{1cm}\Longunderstack{%
    --- sub item 1\\
    --- sub item 2\\
    --- sub item 3
  }%
}
\scalerel[.3cm]{\{}{%
  \Centerstack{%
    $\bullet$ bullet point 1\\
    ~~-- sub-bullet point 1\\
    ~~-- sub-bullet point 2\\
    $\bullet$ bullet point 2
  }%
}

\stackunder{\parbox{5cm}{Description Item 3}}{%
  \hspace{1cm}\Longunderstack{%
    --- sub item 1
  }%
}
\scalerel[.3cm]{\{}{%
  \Centerstack{%
    $\bullet$ bullet point 1\\
    $\bullet$ bullet point 2
  }%
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In response to the OP's request to condition the fonts of the item/sub-items/bullets, one could place these things in a macro `\myitem`, as in this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\parskip .5cm
\newcommand\myitem[3]{%
 \stackunder{\rmfamily\bfseries\parbox{5cm}{#1}}{%
   \hspace{1cm}\itshape\Longunderstack{#2}}%
 \scalerel[.3cm]{\{}{\color{red}\Centerstack{#3}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{frame title}
\myitem{Description Item 1}%
 {%
    --- sub item 1\\
    --- sub item 2
 }%
 {%
    $\bullet$ bullet point 1\\
    $\bullet$ bullet point 2\\
    $\bullet$ bullet point 3
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what if the bullet points (on the right) is organized in several levels ?

Comment: @s__C How is my update?  Does it capture the sub-bullets as you want?

Comment: and what about using the description environment, so that I can parameter \beamerfont{description item} once? I really think a TikZ based solution would be much more efficient and flexible, as everything could be packed inside a \node.

Comment: @s__C I'm sorry, the `description` environment is not in the cards for this approach.  But what does `\beamerfont{description item}` do? (I'm not a beamer person).  Perhaps there is a functional equivalent for my approach.

Comment: any way to limit the brace height to the bullet block height ? it's wasting space on my slides...

Comment: May I ask why \scalerel* is not working in this case ? would solve the vertical space wasted...

Comment: @s__C I did not use a `scalerel*`, which would print out merely the brace to the height of the second argument, WITHOUT printing the second argument.  The `\scalerel` macro, without the star, scales the first argument to the height of the second, AND PRINTS BOTH arguments.

Comment: ok but how to avoid the overheight for the { ? there is a mistake in the height considered I think

Comment: @s__C The `\Centerstack` places a `\strut` on each row, which will expand the top/bottom of the brace.  However, that is necessary in order to properly align the center tick of the brace with the center of the "Description Item".  That is to say, for vertical symmetry of the brace, the rows must be strutted.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a TikZ-based attempt.

## Update

In response to OP's comment, the following code uses a stretched version of the brace character and adjusts the vertical alignment of the braced block. (The red boxes and lines are drawn to show alignments. Comment out the relevant part of the code to switch them off.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand\braceitem[2][]{%
  \hfill%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,yshift=.5ex]
    \node[text width=5cm,align=left,inner sep=0pt] (#1) {\vspace{-8pt}{#2}};
    \path let \p1=(#1.north), \p2=(#1.south), \n1={\y1-\y2} in
      node[xshift=5pt] at(#1.west){\stretchto{\lbrace}{\n1}};
    \draw[red](#1.west)--+(-5cm,0) (#1.north east)rectangle(#1.south west); % comment out
  \end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{50pt}
}
\newcommand\qitem[1]{\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{description}
  \item[description item 1] \braceitem[A]{\qitem{
    \item some bullet points \qitem{
      \item sub bullet point
      \item sub bullet point
    }
    \item some other bullet points
  }}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item sub item 1
    \item sub item 2
  \end{itemize}

  \vskip20pt

  \item[description item 2] \braceitem[B]{\begin{itemize}\item some other bullet point\item bullet \qitem{\item sub bullet \item sub bullet}\end{itemize}}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item sub item 1
    \item sub item 2
    \item sub item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{description}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[] description item 1
    \braceitem[c]{\qitem{\item bullet 1 \qitem{\item sub bullet 1 \item sub bullet 2} \item bullet 2}}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item sub item 1
      \item sub item 2 
      \item sub item 3
    \end{itemize}

  \vskip20pt

  \item[] description item 2
    \braceitem[d]{\qitem{\item bullet 1 \qitem{\item sub bullet 1 \item sub bullet 2} \item bullet 2}}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item sub item 1
      \item sub item 2 
      \item sub item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output of 2nd frame

[image]

---

Personally I prefer the layout in the second frame (using `itemize` instead of `description` for the first level list). The `qitem` command is just a shortcut to save some typing within the `\braceitem` command.

One drawback of this approach is that you'd have to manually adjust the spacing between the description items using `\vskip` or similar.

## Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand\braceitem[2][]{%
  \hfill%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(#1.center)}]%
    \node[text width=9cm,align=left] (#1) {\vspace{-8pt}#2};%
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt},color=blue] (#1.south west) -- (#1.north west); %
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand\qitem[1]{\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{description}
  \item[description item 1] \braceitem[A]{\qitem{
    \item some bullet points \qitem{
      \item sub bullet point
      \item sub bullet point
    }
    \item some other bullet points
  }}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item sub item 1
    \item sub item 2
  \end{itemize}

  \vskip20pt

  \item[description item 2] \braceitem[B]{\begin{itemize}\item some other bullet point\item bullet \qitem{\item sub bullet \item sub bullet}\end{itemize}}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item sub item 1
    \item sub item 2
    \item sub item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{description}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[] description item 1
    \braceitem[c]{\qitem{\item bullet 1 \qitem{\item sub bullet 1 \item sub bullet 2} \item bullet 2}}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item sub item 1
      \item sub item 2 
      \item sub item 3
    \end{itemize}

  \vskip20pt

  \item[] description item 2
    \braceitem[d]{\qitem{\item bullet 1 \qitem{\item sub bullet 1 \item sub bullet 2} \item bullet 2}}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item sub item 1
      \item sub item 2 
      \item sub item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

Frame 1

[image]

Frame 2

[image]

Comment: it does not fulfill the requirement of using the "{" character from the font... plus if you look at my picture the center of the brace is aligned with the description item.

Comment: @s__C: Does the update address your concern?

Comment: well with the { scaling you have to be consistent : either include on top the full height char (like b l k ...) either remove the bottom underline char (like p q y). is it in some ways clear ? plus when the bullets are too long there is an overlap of the text blocks. Plus I'd like to include the sub items in the tikzpicture somehow, so that it could be replaced with text.

Comment: @s__C: your first concern can be addressed by changing `inner sep` to some positive value or adjust the `vspace` parameter. As for long bullet lists, you'd have to manually adjust the spacing between two description items. This is a drawback I admitted in my initial answer. Lastly, I don't understand what you mean by including sub items in the tikzpicture. I don't see this illustrated in the picture you posted.